# collapsible header content with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am struggling writing the appropriate javascript to collapse and expand my content

**View:**

```
<div>
    <h3 id="roleHeader" class="roleHeader collapsible">Title</h3>
    <div>Content to display to users</div>
</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            //collapsible management
            $('.collapsible').collapsible({
            });
        });
```

Comment: which is the `collapsible` plugin used? are you looking for the [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) widget

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean 'accordion'?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement one very easily

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.collapsible').click(function(){
        $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    }).next().hide()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sXkHb/)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `slideToggle`. This function will toggle between sliding the content up and down.

try this

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.collapsible').click(function(){
            $(this).slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
```

500 is the speed of the animation.

You can also target the object you'd like to hide and show. Either give it an Id, class, or target it specifically with jQuery. Here, when you click on anything that has a class of `collapsible`, the next `div` will hide and show.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".collapsible").click(function(){
            $(this).next("div").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
```

If you need the animation to stop when you click on it again to prevent a jumping effect, add `.stop(true)` before the effect

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".collapsible").click(function(){
            $(this).next("div").stop(true).slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
```